# WordPress Calendar - ACF?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, calendar, advanced-custom-fields

I am looking for a WordPress calendar, which can do the following:

- Organize by category, for example Indoor event and Outdoor Event
- Set the event in a post, for example - have a custom post type, and be able to add the event to this, the same way FT Calendar does ( See image below )
  [image: FTCalendar]

FT Calendar is good, but I need to be able to organize the calender by categories, so you can select multiple categories, such as SpiderCalender.

Anyone got any ideas?

---

EDIT:

The best way I can think of, is to just make one. The calendar doesn't need to be huge, just the basic for now.

I was reading this post - http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/query-between-dates-using-date-picker-fields/

and created an ACF for my events, named start_date and end_date.

I just have no idea where to start! How to even get the start and end dates to show in a calendar?

~EDIT

Also found this?:
I don't know any plugin like this. Anyway, you should provide specific information of what kind of calendar you want. By general means, strtotime is your friend.

For example, to generate a day listing of the current month with a highlighted date from the custom field, you would do something like:

```
$date_field = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( get_field( 'date_field' ) ) );
$current_month = date( 'Y-m-' );
for ( $day = 1; $day < date( 't' ); $day++ ) {
    $day_of_month = $current_month . $day;
    if ( $day_of_month == $date_field )
        <span class="highlight"><?php echo $day_of_month; ?></span>
    else
        <span class="normal"><?php echo $day_of_month; ?></span>
}
```

> Note: the above code is not tested.

Comment: ever find a solution? I'm having to do something similar now

Comment: The Events Calendar Pro by Modern Tribe will do just about anything. You can do categorization. Attaching the event to a particular post could be done in a variety of ways.